# NSImage -initWithContentsOfFile returns an image of size zero (0)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

To load icon images, I have the below code in one of the methods:

```
NSLog(@"icon path: %@", iconPath);
NSImage *iconImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:iconPath];
return iconImage;
```

From the log output, it is clear that image resources are being opened from the correct location. I don't see errors. Yet, tif files that I open are shown to have empty NSSize (width=0, height=0) in debugger, and displayed on the screen as if I am pointing to some runaway memory segment.

Flags are mainly set to 0. The exceptions are colorMatchPreferred and multipleResolutionMatching set to 1.

Reps points to an array (NSArrayM *) containing two (2) bitmap representations (NSBitmapImageRep entries).

Please advise what am I doing wrong!

Thank you

Comment: Please include the full exception text and stacktrace.

Comment: There are no exceptions and hence no stacktrace.

Comment: OK, I was confused by the statement " The exceptions are colorMatchPreferred and multipleResolutionMatching set to 1".

Comment: First load the content with NSData, then use [NSImage initWithData:]. There are some caching mechanisms.

Comment: I tried to use: NSData *iconImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:iconPath]; NSImage *iconImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:iconImageData];

It shows that my data is indeed being loaded. Number of loaded bytes varies depending on the image. This seems to be good. The change did not affect the end result, however. The size is still 0x0 and something funky is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
//to get image original size use this code

NSArray * imageReps = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepsWithContentsOfFile:fileUrl];  
        NSInteger width = 0;
        NSInteger height = 0;

        for (NSImageRep * imageRep in imageReps)
        {
            if ([imageRep pixelsWide] > width)
                width = [imageRep pixelsWide];
            if ([imageRep pixelsHigh] > height)
                height = [imageRep pixelsHigh];
        }
```